# Conditional Where with Join

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I need to return a list of clients that match the provided identifying fields that are in a separate table using LINQ. The SQL statement would look like the following if it was in a stored procedure:

```
Select client.*
From ADLT_Clients as client
    Inner Join ADLT_ClientIdentifiers as identifier
        on client.ClientPIN = identifier.ClientPIN
Where identifier.EmailAdrs = @EmailAddress
    and identifier.FBINum = @FBINumber
    (...)
```

I am trying to do this in LINQ with the following:

```
    Public Function FindByIndentifiers(adultClient As AdultClient) As List(Of AdultClient)
        Dim adultClients As New List(Of AdultClient)
        Dim clients = From client As ADLT_Client In _cmisiiEntities.ADLT_Clients
                      Join identifier In _cmisiiEntities.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers On client.ClientPIN Equals identifier.ClientPIN
                      Select client

        If adultClient.AdultClientIdentifiers IsNot Nothing Then
            With adultClient.AdultClientIdentifiers
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.EmailAddress) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.EMailAdrs.Contains(.EmailAddress))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.FBINumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.FBINum.Contains(.FBINumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.ICOTSNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.ICOTSNum.Contains(.ICOTSNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.InmateNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.InmateNum.Contains(.InmateNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.LicenseNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.LicenseNum.Contains(.LicenseNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.LicenseNumberState) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.LicenseNumState.Contains(.LicenseNumberState))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.PassportNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.PassportNum.Contains(.PassportNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.AlienRegistrationNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.GreenCardNum.Contains(.AlienRegistrationNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.SocialSecurityNumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.SSN.Contains(.SocialSecurityNumber))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.SPBINumber) Then clients = clients.Where(Function(f) f.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers.SPBINum.Contains(.SPBINumber))
            End With
        End If

        For Each client In clients.Take(100).ToList()
            adultClients.Add(BuildAdultClient(client))
        Next

        Return adultClients
    End Function
```

When this code executes with no valid parameters, none of the where clauses are added and the clients.Take(100).ToList() statement executes fine. If I include any valid parameter, thus adding a where clause, the statement gives a NullReferenceException on the ToList() call.

My theory is that the there is an alias problem with the where clauses I am trying to add. When the where clauses are part of the initial statement I use the identifier alias created by the join statement. If I modify my statement to be this:

```
            Dim clients = (From client As ADLT_Client In _cmisiiEntities.ADLT_Clients
                      Join identifier In _cmisiiEntities.ADLT_ClientIdentifiers On client.ClientPIN Equals identifier.ClientPIN) _
                      .Where(Function(f) f.identifier.EMailAdrs.Contains(adultClient.EmailAddress)) _
                      .Select(Function(f) f.client)
```

The code will execute as well. The difference here is that I am going through the defined identifier alias. I cannot do the same f.identifier.EmailAdrs in my conditional where statements because identifier is not part of that context?

Am I missing something here, is there a better way to do this properly, or is this a limitation of VB?

Comment: I have to wonder if this is a VB issue with the expressions having issues around you using a `With` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do this in linqPad, with linq2Sql

```
Dim c as new Config with {.Category="Other"}
Dim q =from c1 in  Configs select c1

if(c isnot nothing) then
    if not string.isnullorempty(c.Category) then q=q.Where(Function(f) f.Category.Contains(c.Category))
end if
q.Dump()
```

it works, however if I do this

```
Dim c as new Config with {.Category="Other"}
Dim q =from c1 in  Configs select c1

if(c isnot nothing) then
    with c
        if not string.isnullorempty(.Category) then q=q.Where(Function(f) f.Category.Contains(.Category))
    end with
end if
q.Dump()
```

it throws a null reference exception. I think it is your with clauses clashing with expressions

Comment: Removing the "With adultClient.AdultClientIdentifiers" from my code solved it. Thanks